# Not able to understand this graph property.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

I read that in a simple graph, |minimal vertex cover| $\leq  2$|maximal matching|.

Consider a graph show below.
Here a minimal vertex cover can be $\{B,C,D,E\}$ which has a size of 4 and size of maximal matching is just 1.
So, $4>2*1$ and the property doesn't seem to satisfy.

Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is that the $|\text{Smallest Vertex Cover}|\leq 2|\text{Maximal Matching}|$, not minimal.

If you have a maximal Matching $M$ and you choose the vertices of the edges of $M$ you have a vertex cover of $2|M|$ vertices. This covers every edge because a not covered edge could be added to $M$, which cannot be because $M$ is maximal.

If we have one Vertex cover with size $2|M|$, the smallest must be smaller or equal in size. As your example shows one cannot replace smallest with minimal.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a graph where minimum vertex cover is exactly equal to 2|M| ? Actually in my graph theory course our professor said that |minimal matching| <= |minimal vertex cover| <= 2*|maximal matching | and I was just trying to verify that.

Comment: If you take a Cycle of uneven length you have equality for example. Minimal and maximal are tricky words. |Largest Matching|<=|Smallest Vertex Cover|<=2|Largest Matching| is true. Maybe that's what he meant.

Comment: Thanks . I think that the first part of the inequality which is |maximal matching| <=|minimal vertex cover| is true because we can take a single vertex from each of the edges satisfying the maximal matching property and form a vertex cover which is minimal.